# Is it possible to change google sheets via script on android?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet with a checkbox in it and an "onEdit" code in script. When checked, it is supposed to run the below-mentioned code.

It works fine when I run it on my laptop, but not functioning at all, when I run it on my phone.

What am i doing wrong?

Code:

```
function onEdit(e) {

  if (e.range.getA1Notation() == 'C25') {
    const rg = e.range;
    if(rg.isChecked() && rg.getSheet().getName() === "B2 data"){
       var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Ændringer");
      sheet.activate();
      rg.uncheck();
    }
  }
```

Comment: If this is using a simple trigger then the function name needs to be onEdit otherwise you may need to create an installable trigger.

Comment: Thanks! The function name is onEdit and works fine on desktop. I don't understand why it isn't working on the phone

Comment: In your example the function name is not onEdit

Comment: Perhaps you have more than one onEdit function

Comment: Perhaps you should report it as an issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new)

Comment: Every function in a project must have a unique name so two functions named onEdit is not allowed.

Comment: I've updated my post with the onEdit code (unedited so it is in my native language). I have only a single onEdit and no duplicate named functions.

Comment: Yes it doesn't work on my phone either.  Perhaps you should report it as a issue.

Comment: That's odd. Where do I report it?

Comment: There's a link in the support section of the documentation and one of my comments above